# Free MySQL Profiler

Tags: mysql

My Background is with MS-SQL and not MySQL and I am struggeling to figure out how to debug something,

I need to see exactly what querys (actually inserts) a webservice is executing in a MySQL database, However I cannot find an equivelent to MS-SQL Profiler that is free (we have no budget).  Does anyone have any suggestions?

Thanks

Ian

Answer (score 4):

Try that:

```
mysql> SET profiling = 1;

mysql> SELECT * FROM {your_table}

mysql> SHOW PROFILES;
```

or

```
mysql> SHOW PROFILE;
```

More info:
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/show-profile.html

Comment: '@@profiling' is deprecated and will be removed in a future release. Use PERFORMANCE_SCHEMA  instead.

Answer (score 1):

You need to turn on general SQL log - [The General Query Log](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/query-log.html). You can specify where to log queries - table or file.